# join html lines using sed

Tags: html, linux, sed

I have a url within a html td tag split across multiple lines that I need to join.

Example:

```
<td>
<a
href="fix_detail.jsp?fix=23056&list=yes">PICTURE
ROCKS</a>&nbsp;
</td>
```

I need to join everything to look like this:

```
<a href="fix_detail.jsp?fix=23056&list=yes">PICTURE ROCKS</a>&nbsp;</td>
```

I would prefer to implemnt a sed loop, but I don't understand how to loop searching for the closing "td" tag.

```
sed '/<td>$/N;s/\n/ /;N;s/\n/ /;N;s/\n/ /;N;s/\n/ /'
```

Comment: You want the initial `<td>` removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sed one liner

```
sed '/<td>/{:loop;/<\/td>/!{N;s/\n/ /}; t loop}' file
```

That outputs

```
<td> <a href="fix_detail.jsp?fix=23056&list=yes">PICTURE ROCKS</a>&nbsp; </td>
```

It does this by first matching the "< td>", then it starts a loop that appends lines, and terminates when it reaches the "< /td>" tag.

Comment: Well done! You could have used a different delimiter yet in this case it would be more work than to simply escape it. If he really doesn't want the `<td>` tag on the same line you can just add an `n` before the group: `sed '/<td>/{n;{:loop;/<\/td>/!{N;s/\n/ /}; t loop}}'`

Answer (score 2):

Keep your sanity, just use awk:

```
$ cat file
foo
<td>
<a
href="fix_detail.jsp?fix=23056&list=yes">PICTURE
ROCKS</a>&nbsp;
</td>
bar

$ awk '/<td>/{f=1} /<\/td>/{f=0} {ORS=(f?" ":"\n"); print}' file
foo
<td> <a href="fix_detail.jsp?fix=23056&list=yes">PICTURE ROCKS</a>&nbsp; </td>
bar
```

all of the arcane sed constructs to do things across multiple lines became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented, they are only used today as a brain-teaser.